# How to reset SVG animation in owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, html, svg, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have svg animation, made like this

```
<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='16' 
height='16' viewbox='0 0 250 250' enable-background='new 0 0 426.667 410' 
xml:space='preserve'><path class='loader' transform='translate(125, 125) 
scale(.84)'/>
</svg>
```

JS for animating

```
var loader = document.getElementsByClassName("loader")
    , a = 0
    , p = Math.PI
    , t = 9;

(function draw() {
    a++;
    a %= 360;
    var r = ( a * p / 180 )
        , x = Math.sin( r ) * 125
        , y = Math.cos( r ) * - 125
        , mid = ( a > 180 ) ? 1 : 0
        , anim = "M 0 0 v -125 A 125 125 1 "
        + mid + " 1 "
        +  x  + " "
        +  y  + " z";

    Object.values(loader).forEach(item=>item.setAttribute("d",anim));

    setTimeout(draw, t); // Redraw
}());
```

and css

```
svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    border: 3px solid pink;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
svg path {display: none;}
.owl-dot.active svg path {display: block;}
```

css is mainly for display swg when class active is setted. It is in carousel, so i need to display just one animation for each slide. But the problem is, that all svg are animating at the same time. I need to reset these animations everytime, when carousel change slide. For carousel is used Owl-Carousel with simple code :

```
$("#our-work-carousel2").owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        lazyLoad: true,
        autoplay: true,
        animateIn: 'fadeIn',
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        slideSpeed: 300,
        paginationSpeed: 400,
        dotData: true,
        dotsData: true,
        itemsDesktop: false,
        itemsDesktopSmall: false,
        itemsTablet: true,
        itemsMobile: false,
        onChange:callback,
    });

   function callback(event){
   }
```

I would probably need some code in callback for reset svg animation, but i can´t figure out this solution. Thanks to all for every advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation state is updated based on the variable `a`, on each step of the animation the variable is increased by one, until reaching 360, then return to 0.

To reset the animation you need to reset the variable `a` setting the value 0.

```js
var loader = document.getElementsByClassName("loader")
    , a = 0
    , p = Math.PI
    , t = 9;

(function draw() {
    a++;
    a %= 360;
    var r = ( a * p / 180 )
        , x = Math.sin( r ) * 125
        , y = Math.cos( r ) * - 125
        , mid = ( a > 180 ) ? 1 : 0
        , anim = "M 0 0 v -125 A 125 125 1 "
        + mid + " 1 "
        +  x  + " "
        +  y  + " z";

    Object.values(loader).forEach(item=>item.setAttribute("d",anim));

    console.log('a:', a);
    setTimeout(draw, t); // Redraw
}());

document.getElementById('reset-loader').addEventListener('click', () => a = 0);
```

```css
svg {
    border: 3px solid pink;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='16' 
height='16' viewbox='0 0 250 250' enable-background='new 0 0 426.667 410' 
xml:space='preserve'><path class='loader' transform='translate(125, 125) 
scale(.84)'/>
</svg>

<button id="reset-loader">reset</button>
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you so much!